# What is the most efficient database structure for group chat messages?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm deciding about the database structure for the `messages` node of my group chat app. Following are the two structures in consideration:

Option 1:

```
"messages" : {
  "-MDQs5CjIFbIPV24XSHX" : { // Group chat Id
    "-MDQt6gYsxrwislwSItN" : { // Message Id
      "_id" : "-MDQt6gYsxrwislwSItN",
      "creationDate" : 1596048309540,
      "messageType" : "type_text",
      "senderId" : "cOEwux6gjpPoZSQ9h3PHcFz5X8g1",
      "senderName" : "User 1",
      "text" : "Hi"
      }
    }  
  }
```

Option 2:

```
"messages" : {
  "-MDQt6gYsxrwislwSItN" : { // Message Id
    "_id" : "-MDQt6gYsxrwislwSItN",
    "chatId" : "-MDQs5CjIFbIPV24XSHX", // Chat Id
    "creationDate" : 1596048309540,
    "messageType" : "type_text",
    "senderId" : "cOEwux6gjpPoZSQ9h3PHcFz5X8g1",
    "senderName" : "User 1",
    "text" : "Hi"
    }
  }
```

Option 1 groups messages according to `chatId` while option 2 creates all messages of all group chats directly under one main node. In both options, it is pretty easy to retrieve the messages pertaining to a particular `chatId` which is my main objective.

So would querying messages for a particular chatId be faster in option 1 or option 2 or the same for both?

Comment: I would go option one if you want the messages by group. You don't need the _ID property in either case, that information is already in the record key so you are duplicating unnecessarily.

Comment: But the question is whether there would be any speed benefit if I go for Option 1?

Comment: What 'speed' are you referring to? The speed of Firebase resolving the query, the speed of download, the speed of processing the snapshot returned by the query? In the first case I doubt there is any significant difference. In the second case, which will be by far the major determinant of the overall 'speed', it depends on the size of the dataset. In the third case, depends on your code.

Comment: I'm concerned about which option will result in faster execution of query by Firebase. That's my main question, btw!

Comment: Suggest you read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/optimize and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure. If you're still not satisfied, try Firebase support.